What does "over" mean in this context?

growing faster than any other racial group in the state, according to data released by the U.S. Census Bureau on Thursday. Their numbers increased by 5.5%, or 91,921, OVER the previous year's count.


Over "2a (1): beyond some quantity, limit, or norm often by a specified amount or to a specified degree"

"Over" here means "above", i.e., "more than".

Their numbers increased by 5.5% over the previous year's

means that this year's count was 105.5% of the previous year's count — 5.5% more than (i.e. above, i.e. over) the previous year's.
